# MFC LTEXT (labels) cannot be changed in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, mfc, resources, rc

I am working on a product update that is combining some legacy C++/MFC code with C#/WPF. It uses Visual Studio 2013, update 5. There is an existing MFC dialog that I am trying to modify. Moving elements around with the editor (Resource View->Dialogs, select by ID) worked fine. Changing LTEXT values shows up correctly on the Dialog editor (WYSIWYG you'd think), the changes appear properly in the .rc file (viewed but not edited with Notepad), but the built application shows the rearranged elements with the old labels. I have even went through setting up a clean build machine to ensure there wasn't some strange intermediate file, but no, it just doesn't want to change those labels. I have no idea where to look next.

There is nothing exotic about these labels, here is an abbreviated sample:

```
IDD_MY_DLG DIALOGEX 0, 0, 650, 375
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_CHILD
FONT 8, "Microsoft Sans Serif", 400, 0, 0x0
BEGIN
    LTEXT           "SE Limit",IDC_ISE_LIM_STATIC,457,82,59,8,0,WS_EX_RIGHT
    LTEXT           "NE Limit",IDC_INE_LIM_STATIC,457,112,59,8,0,WS_EX_RIGHT
END
```

The old labels had a colon at the end, that is seriously all I changed on them, but the colons won't go away.

Comment: Do you have duplicate dialogs for different languages? If so, did you change them all? My first thought would be "Rebuild solution" because sometimes VS doesn't "see" that the .rc file has changed and so doesn't recompile it. Try Build/Clean Solution, followed by a Build. Also check for duplicate binaries - especially if this is an OCX or something.

Comment: Try this: exit Visual Studio, delete the .aps and .res files associated with the resource file.  Rebuild.

Comment: Thank you both so much for looking. I'd deleted the .aps, I'd done cleans, both together. Those colons had to be coming from somewhere, so I searched the project for them. I found some code that overrode what was set in the .rc file. Doh! I'd found similar before in this project (inherited) and didn't think to look.

Answer (score 0):

Those colons had to be coming from somewhere, so I searched the project for them. I found some code that overrode what was set in the .rc file. Doh! I'd found similar before in this project (inherited) and didn't think to look.